# is my acer dying? can i do anything to save it? ( updated photo)

Tags: maple

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is a better photo of my acer, it had leaves on but now they have crumbled and dried. is it still alive? is there anything I can do to save it? had it a few years now devastated to say the least.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2yCE.jpg

Comment: You can edit your question to update and include new information pictures, rather than asking a new question. I have done that for this picture on your original question. You can choose "delete" under this question to tidy up.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again ?

Comment: No need to be rude Rohit! I'm new here and just learning the site!